# Customizing sharepoint 2016 ribbon

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

It's possible to move the gear icon and profile name to another div on sharepoint 2016 ?

I want to move gear and user name from the black ribbon to my own ribbon div.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The good news is, yes you can replace and modify the location, the bade new is, you will need to create a custom Master Page to replace the current one

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to separate out the ribbon elements ?

Comment: Do you mean, the groups inside of each ribbon or the pages on the ribbon?

Comment: I mean, Moving the elements like profile name, gear icon into other div.

Comment: Got it. Yes and you can place then anywhere, it all depends on how keep the Master Page responsive, you can hide, you can even remove them completely or put them on the bottom or left/right, it is up to you, do you have any experience creating Master Pages?

Comment: do you have any idea how can it be customized? from some research, I too have found out that it can be done but its hardly written anywhere how it can be actually done.